# Tool to explain C code

Tags: c

I remember from some time ago reading about a commandline tool that explains C code, does anyone know what it might be named?

Comment: What kind of explanation are you talking about? A little more specifics, please :)

Comment: More on-topic question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448849/how-do-i-understand-complicated-function-declarations

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Perhaps you mean cdecl, a program that can translate complicated declarations to English and back?

e.g.

```
cdecl> explain int (*(*foo)(int ))(float )
declare foo as pointer to function (int) returning pointer to function (float) returning int
```

Comment: That's a very nice program by the sound of it. Does it have a home page somewhere?

Comment: It is a small program and you will find several versions of the source floating around.  Most Linux systems that I have encountered seem to have it installed.  I believe K&R is the original source.  The book uses the program as tool to explain complicated declarations.

Comment: Is there a similar program for parsing complex / obfuscated expressions per chance? (with operator precedence & stuff)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean explaining then I think the answers already been given. If you mean looking for potential problems then there's lint and its variants, first stop in any code review.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_programming_tool

Edit:
[C/C++ Free alternative to Lint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632057/c-c-free-alternative-to-lint)

HTH