# Can you explain the following C/C++ statement?

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

```
void (*func)(int(*[ ])());
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448849/how-to-understand-complicated-function-declarations

Answer (score 31):

The general procedure for reading hairy declarators is to find the leftmost identifier and work your way out, remembering that `[]` and `()` bind before `*` (i.e., `*a[]` is an array of pointer, not a pointer to an array).  This case is made a little more difficult by the lack of an identifier in the parameter list, but again, `[]` binds before `*`, so we know that `*[]` indicates an array of poitners.

So, given

```
void (*func)(int(*[ ])());
```

we break it down as follows:

```
       func                   -- func
      *func                   -- is a pointer
     (*func)(           )     -- to a function taking
     (*func)(     [ ]   )     --    an array
     (*func)(    *[ ]   )     --    of pointers
     (*func)(   (*[ ])())     --    to functions taking 
                              --      an unspecified number of parameters
     (*func)(int(*[ ])())     --    returning int
void (*func)(int(*[ ])());    -- and returning void
```

What this would look like in practice would be something like the following:

```
/**
 * Define the functions that will be part of the function array
 */
int foo() { int i; ...; return i; }
int bar() { int j; ...; return j; }
int baz() { int k; ...; return k; }
/**
 * Define a function that takes the array of pointers to functions
 */
void blurga(int (*fa[])())
{
  int i;
  int x;
  for (i = 0; fa[i] != NULL; i++)
  {
    x = fa[i](); /* or x = (*fa[i])(); */
    ...
  }
}    
...
/**
 * Declare and initialize an array of pointers to functions returning int
 */
int (*funcArray[])() = {foo, bar, baz, NULL};
/**
 * Declare our function pointer
 */
void (*func)(int(*[ ])());
/**
 * Assign the function pointer
 */
func = blurga;
/**
 * Call the function "blurga" through the function pointer "func"
 */
func(funcArray); /* or (*func)(funcArray); */
```

Comment: +1 for good enough try to explain how to read such expressions and example.

Answer (score 20):

It's not a statement, it's a declaration.

It declares `func` as a pointer to a function returning void and taking a single argument of type `int (*[])()`, which itself is a pointer to a pointer to a function returning int and taking a fixed but unspecified number of arguments.

---

**cdecl output for ye of little faith:**

```
cdecl> explain void (*f)(int(*[ ])());
declare f as pointer to function (array of pointer to function returning int) returning void
```

Comment: "fixed but unspecified number of arguments" - the question is also tagged C++, in which case that second function type takes precisely zero arguments.

Comment: The C++ tag was added by someone other than the original poster, after I'd answered.  A move too-clever-by-half, by my book.

Comment: Gosh, that is sneaky. It's never clear when someone says "C/C++" whether they've said it because they think the answer is the same for both languages, because they think the answers is different between the two...

Comment: +1, i just wanna explain why you say "pointer to pointer" and cdecl says "array of pointer": this is because in functions, parameters declared as arrays become pointers. Just so no-one says "hey, you have a typo" :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes:

```
$ cdecl
explain void (* x)(int (*[])());
declare x as pointer to function 
  (array of pointer to function returning int) returning void
```

Comment: I don't think it is, cdecl just doesn't like the name `func`.

Comment: Nahhhh ... it's a bug in cdecl :)

Comment: It shows you cheated, lulz (btw it's a good cheat, cdecl is nice xD)

Answer (score 2):

`void (*func)(blah);` is a pointer to a function taking `blah` as an argument, where `blah` itself is `int(*[ ])()` is an array of function pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a guide on reading C declarations:

http://www.ericgiguere.com/articles/reading-c-declarations.html

Answer (score 2):

[`Geordi`](http://www.xs4all.nl/~weegen/eelis/geordi/) is a C++ bot, allowing to train this:

```
<litb> geordi: {} void (*func)(int(*[ ])());
<litb> geordi: -r << ETYPE_DESC(func)
<geordi> lvalue pointer to a function taking a pointer to a pointer to a nullary function 
         returning an integer and returning nothing
```

It can do many useful things, like showing all parameter-declarations (this, in fact, is just matching raw `C++` grammar rule names):

```
<litb> geordi: show parameter-declarations
<geordi> `int(*[ ])()`.
```

Let's do it in the opposite direction:

```
<litb> geordi: {} int func;
<litb> geordi: make func a pointer to function returning void and taking array of pointer to 
       functions returning int
<litb> geordi: show
<geordi> {} void (* func)(int(*[])());
```

It executes anything you give to it, if you ask it. If you are trained but just forgot some of the scary parentheses rules, you may also mix C++ and geordi-style type descriptions:

```
<litb> geordi: make func a (function returning void and taking (int(*)()) []) *
<geordi> {} void (* func)(int(*[])());
```

Have fun!