# Complicated declarations (of C)

Tags: c, syntax, declaration

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How to understand complicated function declarations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448849/how-to-understand-complicated-function-declarations) 
>   [Spiral rule and ‘declaration follows usage’ for parsing C expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707096/spiral-rule-and-declaration-follows-usage-for-parsing-c-expressions)

There is a section with the same title, "Complicated Declarations", in [K&R's The C Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628)  book as you might have already read. I am just reading the book and trying to better myself in C language. After reading the section mentioned, I think I couldn't get the logic behind the syntax of C declaration statements. 1, 2, 3 and 4  are from that section 5 and 6 are from other pages.

1. `int (*daytab)[13]`
   daytab: pointer to array[13] of int
2. `void (*comp)()`
   comp: pointer to function returning void
3. `char (*(*x())[])()`
    x: function returning pointer to array[] of pointer to function returning char
4. `char (*(*x[3])())[5]`
   x: array[3] of pointer to function returning pointer to array[5] of
   char
5. `typedef int (*PFI)(char *, char *)`
   creates the type PFI, for ``pointer to function (of two char *
   arguments) returning int. How does the syntax works here?

Finally, my questions are:

- Can you explain your ways of thinking and reading complicated
  declarations possibly by using examples above?
- Are the things like
      1,3,4 practically usable and needed? If so, can you write some code examples?

Comment: Are you sure that int (*daytab)[13]
declares daytab array[13] of pointer to int?

Comment: @PascalCuoq it doesn't, it's a pointer to an array of 13 ints.

Comment: @SethCarnegie I know you know that. I was asking the OP.

Answer (score 6):

I saw [The ``Clockwise/Spiral Rule''](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) on HackerNews in the past week or so.  It is a good way to think about C declarations, especially function pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the identifier and the symbol next to it to the right:

- If it's a `[` the identifier is for an array.
- If it is a `(` the identifier is for a function
- If it is a `)` look to the left and you will find a `*`: the identifier is a pointer
- If there is nothing to the right or to the left, the identifier is a "plain old" object.

Elaboration:

1. `int (*daytab)[13]` 
   `daytab` is a pointer
2. `void (*comp)()` 
   `comp` is a pointer
3. `char (*(*x())[])()` 
   `x` is a function
4. `char (*(*x[3])())[5]` 
   `x` is an array
5. `typedef int (*PFI)(char *, char *)` 
   `PFI` is a pointer

Comment: Could you please give the complete meanings of each of these examples? Thanks a lot!