# What does the following c code means?

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef

```
typedef int (*http_data_cb) (http_parser*, const char *at, size_t length);
```

As far as I know, **typedef** assigns new name to types in standard library.In this situation an instance of `*http_data_cb` is an int, but how about `(http_parser*, const char *at, size_t length)`?

Here is the link of the [whole code](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ALEXBIO/Git-Raw-0.14/xs/libgit2/deps/http-parser/http_parser.h)

Thanks,

Comment: @KingsIndian it doesnt recognize, it says syntax error

Comment: because `http_parser` is not defined. Probably also a typedeffed type.

Comment: @wildplasser, it is not related to that. I tried by changing it. If you dont believe me try yourself.

Comment: I don't have to try. I *know* that `http_parser` is neither a type name nor a keyword in C. I just checked: it is a typedeffed incomplete type.

Comment: I changed http_parser to int then tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**http_data_cb** : is a variable

**(*http_data_cb)**: is a pointer variable

**(*http_data_cb)(...)**: is a pointer variable to a function

**(*http_data_cb)(http_parser*, const char *at, size_t length)**: is a pointer variable to a function that recieves (http_parser*, const char *at, size_t length)

**int (*http_data_cb)(http_parser*, const char *at, size_t length)**: is a pointer variable to a function that recieves (http_parser*, const char *at, size_t length) and returns an int.

**typedef int (*http_data_cb)(http_parser*, const char *at, size_t length):** http_data_cb is declared to be a new datatype alias as a pointer variable to a function that recieves (http_parser*, const char *at, size_t length) and returns an int.

Comment: @virtuecan You might want to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448849/how-to-understand-complicated-function-declarations

I learned it actually from there :)

Comment: Or rather, `int (*http_data_cb)(...)`, with the return type specified, is a function pointer.

Comment: Thanks Noor, appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

It is a way do typedef a type that is a pointer to function. Typically in such typedefs you would not name the arguments to the function, but only indicate their type.

So a variable of the type `http_data_cb` will be a pointer to a function returning int result and taking three arguments of type `http_parser*`, `const char` and `size_t` in this order.

Comment: I won't say that you typically not name the arguments as for documentation reasons it's often valuable to have names for the arguments. Of course they are optional but in my opinion highly recommended.

Comment: `http_data_cb(InstanceOfParser, string_ptr, string_len);` is going to return me an int, right?

Comment: @virtuecan in fact you do something of the sort of `http_data_cb f=<some_func_name>;(*f)(InstanceOfParser, string_ptr, string_len);`

Answer (score 1):

It declares a *function pointer* type.

The type-alias `http_data_cb` is a pointer to a function that receives three arguments and returns an integer.

You can use that to have pointers to other functions, for example to pass as callbacks in an event-driven system.

For more help reading and understanding declarations, see e.g. [the clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: `http_data_cb(InstanceOfParser, string_ptr, string_len);` is going to return me an int, right?

Comment: @virtuecan Yes, if you declare a variable of type `http_data_cb` and make it point to a functin with the correct signature, then you can use your variable (not the type) as a function and it should return an integer.

Comment: Thanks for help, if I had enough reputation would vote your comment up :(