# Semantics of int (*ptr)();?

Tags: c, syntax, function-pointers

```
int (*ptr)();
```

Can someone ELI5 what this code snippet does? I find it almost impossible to visually or logically make sense of it.

Also how and when is it used?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448849/how-to-understand-complicated-function-declarations

Comment: Is it a function? (Sorry for being new to C)

Comment: Ptr is a pointer to a function taking no parameters and returning an int, I believe.

Comment: "ELI5"? http://xkcd.com/1364/

Comment: [online cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) says it's a syntax error!

Comment: @EJP Thats impossible. The program it belongs to works https://gist.github.com/vivekr98/5898434

Comment: I agree entirely. It's cdecl.org that disagrees.

Comment: cdecl.org appears to treat "ptr" as a reserved alias for "pointer". Replacing the name with "foo" causes it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a pointer, named ptr, to a function that returns an int and takes no arguments (i.e., `int ()`).

The syntax isn't beautiful, but it's like a function signature, except the second part identifies that this is a pointer to such a function, with a certain name (ptr in this case).

[This tutorial](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html#defi) might be of help in understanding the principles (excerpt follows):

```
int (*pt2Function)(float, char, char) = NULL;                        // C

int DoIt  (float a, char b, char c){ printf("DoIt\n");   return a+b+c; }
int DoMore(float a, char b, char c)const{ printf("DoMore\n"); return a-b+c; }

pt2Function = DoIt;      // short form
pt2Function = &DoMore;   // correct assignment using address operator
```

Comment: As for how you might use it, you might implement two functions that take `void` and return `int` that represent two ways to roll dice.  Depending on control flow in the program, you might want to switch to normal or cheating dice.  Using a function pointer, you avoid needing an if-else statement in the implementation and can instead assign the pointer directly, e.g. `int CheatingRoll(){...} ... ptr = &CheatingRoll;`

Comment: @MooseBoys lol cheatingdice. I took int (*ptr)(); from a Remote ShellCode Launcher. Close enough

Answer (score 1):

Read it from inside to outside.

`(*ptr)` - it's a pointer variable named `ptr`. Replace it with some symbol, say A.
`int A();` - it's a function taking no arguments and returning `int`.

Now recall what A is. Combine it. The answer is: this declares a variable, named `ptr`, which is a pointer to a function that takes no arguments and returns `int`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a function pointer, which points to a function that returns an int type.

Before calling a function through a pointer, it is necessary to initialize the pointer to actually point to a function.

Here is an example of calling 'atoi()' using a function pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int (*ptr)(const char *nptr) = atoi;

int main()
    {

    printf("%d\n", (*ptr)("42");

    return(0);
    }
```