# Function pointer expression

Tags: c++, pointers

So I've got the following expression:

```
int (*f1(int(*a)(int, int))) (int, int);
```

and I'm trying to make sense out of it, but it's confusing. I figured out that "a" is a pointer to a function which takes 2 arguments(int, int).
Then f1 seems to be a pointer to another function that takes 2 int arguments. 
But what's confusing me is how f1 relates to a.

Can someone give me some hints or properly explain what the above expression is doing?

Comment: Please tell me why are people writing C++ code using function pointers. std::function is available

Comment: That's not the point of the question. I've got this line, I'm trying to figure out what it means and I'm stuck.

Comment: That is why it is a comment? But one should think seriously why is one doing this

Comment: https://cdecl.org/ says: "declare f1 as function (pointer to function (int, int) returning int) returning pointer to function (int, int) returning int"

Comment: See also: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I understand complicated function declarations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448849/how-do-i-understand-complicated-function-declarations) I do see that that question is about C, while this one is about C++, but this one doesn't have anything C++-specific.

Answer (score 10):

It declares `f1` as a function with a single parameter called `a`. Both type of the parameter and return type are "pointer to function with two `int` parameters returning `int`".

---

Here's how you parse it:

```
// f1 is...
      f1
// ...a function...
      f1(                 )
// ...with a single parameter called `a`, which is...
      f1(     a           )
// ...a pointer to...
      f1(    *a           )
// (skip parentheses)
      f1(   (*a)          )
// ...a function...
      f1(   (*a)(        ))
// ...with two `int` parameters...
      f1(   (*a)(int, int))
// ...returning an `int`. The `f1` itself returns...
      f1(int(*a)(int, int))
// ...a pointer to...
     *f1(int(*a)(int, int))
// (skip parentheses)
    (*f1(int(*a)(int, int)))
// ...a function...
    (*f1(int(*a)(int, int))) (        )
// ...with two int parameters...
    (*f1(int(*a)(int, int))) (int, int)
// ...returning an `int`.
int (*f1(int(*a)(int, int))) (int, int)
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a declaration of the function `f1` which takes a parameter `a`- a pointer to function which takes 2 `int`s as argument and returns an `int` - and returns a pointer to function of the same type.

Breaking it down with a typedef:

```
typedef int(*t)(int, int);

t f1(t a); //this is your declaration
```

Answer (score 5):

The tip in C is to read a declaration as it were an expression. This is this famous symmetrie that make C elegant.

How to read it? following the operators precedence rules:

1. `*a`: if I dereference variable `a`;
2. `(*a)(int,int)`: and then call it with two integers;
3. `int (*a)(int,int)`: then I get an integer;

So `a` is a pointer to a function taking two `int`s as parameter and returning an int.

Then:

5. `f( int(*a)(int,int) )` if I call f with the argument `a`;
6. `*f( int(*a)(int,int) )` and then I dereference the result;
7. `(*f( int(*a)(int,int) )(int,int)` and then call this result with 2 `int` as argument
8. `int (*f( int(*a)(int,int) )(int,int)` I get an `int`

So `f` is a function taking an `a` as argument and returning a pointer to a function that take two `int`s as argument and returning an `int`. So `f` return type is the same as its argument return type. It could have been simpler:

```
using ftype = int(*)(int,int);
ftype f( ftype a);
```

Comment: Note that the way C++ extends this C syntax with references does not appear to follow this pattern. E.g. `int &x;` declares `x` as a reference to `int`, but it doesn't mean that `&x` has type `int` (it actually has type `int*`). So this is all true only if your declaration doesn't have references in it.

Comment: Arhhh reference are monsters: const pointers with pointed object semantic.

Answer (score 4):

`a` is the name of `f1`'s only parameter; when you remove it, then you can use https://cdecl.org/ to decipher the entire declaration:

> declare f1 as function (pointer to function (int, int) returning int)
>   returning pointer to function (int, int) returning int

So `f1` is a function. It takes a function pointer (called `a`) and it returns a function pointer.

Both of those function pointers are for functions which take two `int`s and return an `int`.

Here is an example to see it all in action:

```
#include <iostream>

int passed(int x, int y) { std::cout << "passed\n"; return x * y; }
int returned(int x, int y) { std::cout << "returned\n"; return x + y; }

// a is redundant here, where we just declare f1:
int (*f1(int(*a)(int, int))) (int, int);

// but not here, where we define f1:
int (*f1(int(*a)(int, int))) (int, int)
{
    std::cout << "f1\n";
    int result_of_passed = a(10, 10);
    std::cout << result_of_passed << '\n';
    return returned;
}

int main()
{
    int x = f1(passed)(10, 10);
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
f1
passed
100
returned
20
```