# syntax confusion with arrays and pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Consider the following:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int number;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} node;


node  test[511];
node  *test1 = malloc(511 * sizeof(node));
node  (*test2)[511] = malloc(511 * sizeof(node));
```

is the following correct:

1. test is an array of 511 nodes. we can access each node with test[i] where i is the node we want
2. test1 is a pointer where we malloc space for 511 nodes.  we can access each node with test1[i]

so are test and test1 basically the same except test is on the stack and test1 on the heap?

test2 looks like a pointer to an array.  does malloc allocate 511 * sizeof(node) to each pointer or to the entire array? if the later then can we access each node with test2[i] and if the former can do the following:

```
node  (*test2)[511] = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

and then access each node with test2[i]?

in general whats the difference between *test1 and (*test2)?

Comment: Why have you chosen the [tag:operator-precedence] tag?

Comment: `test1` and `test` have the same storage class. What's different is the storage of the block to which `test1` points. Don't make the mistake of conflating a pointer with the block it points to. Similarly, `malloc` allocates a block of memory, it does not make sense to say "allocate to (a pointer)" as you write

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `test1` one is referring the `node`. `test2` is referring the array of 511 `node` elements.

`test1 + 1` will reference the next `node` object

`test2 + 1` will reference the next array of 511 `node` objects

> so are test and test1 basically the same except test is on the stack
> and test1 on the heap?

No one is an array which can decay to pointer, another is pointer referencing object of type `node`

When you `malloc` memory it is better to use objects instead of types

```
node  test[511];
node  *test1 = malloc(511 * sizeof(*test1));
node  (*test2)[511] = malloc(511 * sizeof(*test2));
```

```
{
    int number;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} node;

int main(void)
{
    node  test[511];
    node  *test1;
    node  (*test2)[511];

    printf("sizeof test = %zu\n", sizeof(test));
    printf("sizeof *test1 = %zu\n", sizeof(*test1));
    printf("sizeof *test2 = %zu\n", sizeof(*test2));
}
```

```
typedef struct node
{
    int number;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} node;

int main(void)
{
    node  test[511];
    node  *test1;
    node  (*test2)[511];

    printf("sizeof test = %zu\n", sizeof(test));
    printf("sizeof *test1 = %zu\n", sizeof(*test1));
    printf("sizeof *test2 = %zu\n", sizeof(*test2));
}
```

Comment: so what if we do the following:  node (*test2)[1] = malloc(511 * sizeof(*test2));

Comment: it will be pointer to the array having only one element. the size will be the same as the single element. It is logical I think.

Comment: @DCR gcc has even 0 size arrays - just to make it more interesting  https://godbolt.org/z/f7WonY

Answer (score 1):

> in general whats the difference between *test1 and (*test2)?

In this declaration

```
node  *test1 = malloc(511 * sizeof(node));
```

there is declared a pointer to an object of the type `node`. So dereferencing the pointer like `*test1` you will get an object of the type `node`. That is you will get access to the first object of the dynamically allocated array.

In this declaration

```
node  (*test2)[511] = malloc(511 * sizeof(node));
```

there is declared a pointer to an object of the type `node[511]`. That is the pointed object has the array type `node[511]`. Dereferencing the pointer you will get the pointed array that is dynamically allocated.

So `sizeof( *test1 )` is equal to `sizeof( node )`. While `sizeof( *test2 )` is equal to `sizeof( node[511] )` that is the same as `511 * sizeof( node )`.

To access the first element of the allocated array using the pointer `test2` you need at  first to dereference it to get the pointed array that in turn used in an expression with the member access operator -> is converted implicitly to pointer to its first element.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int number;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} node;

int main(void) 
{
    node  *test1 = malloc(511 * sizeof(node));
    node  (*test2)[511] = malloc(511 * sizeof(node));
    
    printf( "sizeof( *test1 ) = %zu\n", sizeof( *test1 ) ); 
    printf( "sizeof( *test2 ) = %zu\n", sizeof( *test2 ) ); 
    
    ( *test1 ).number  = 10;
    ( **test2 ).number = 20;
    
    printf( "test1->number = %d\n", test1->number );
    printf( "( *test2 )->number = %d\n", ( *test2 )->number );
    
    free( test1 );
    free( test2 );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
sizeof( *test1 ) = 24
sizeof( *test2 ) = 12264
test1->number = 10
( *test2 )->number = 20
```

The pointer `test2` could be also initialized for example the following way

```
node  test[511];
node  (*test2)[511] = &test;
```

While the pointer `test1` could be initialized like

```
 node *test1 = test;
```

Comment: but you  ->   node  *test1 = malloc(511 * sizeof(node)); so we've allocated enough space for 511 nodes and can access each one with test[i] .  and in  node  (*test2)[511] = malloc(511 * sizeof(node));; we have an array of 511 pointers, each one pointing to an array of 511 nodes but we only allocated enough for the first pointer

Comment: @DCR  I am sorry I do not see a difference between these two declarations in your comment node *test1 = malloc(511 * sizeof(node)); and node *test1 = malloc(511 * sizeof(node));

Comment: sorry about that.  node *test1 = malloc(511 * sizeof(node)); so we've allocated enough space for 511 nodes and can access each one with test[i] . and in node (*test2)[511] = malloc(511 * sizeof(node));; we have an array of 511 pointers, each one pointing to an array of 511 nodes but we only allocated enough for the first pointer

Comment: hence if we do (*test2)[1] = malloc(511 * sizeof(node)) we now have an array with enough memory and can't we access test2[300]?

Comment: @DCR Careful: `node (*test2)[511]` declares *one* pointer (`test 2`) to an array of 511 nodes. There's no array of 511 pointers. The syntax is confusing. The rule to understand these declarations is called the "right-left" rule (and sometimes the "spiral rule", but [the spiral approach fails in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16260417/3982001)). I recommend these questions: [How do I understand complicated function declarations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1448849/3982001) and [C isn't that hard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34548762/3982001)

Comment: what about node (*test2)[1] = malloc(511 * sizeof(node))? I have a pointer to an array that contains 1 node but i create space for 511 nodes.  thus I can access test2[200][0]?

Comment: @DCR You can consider the following declarations node test[511][1]; node ( *test2 )[1] = test; Or node  ( *test2 )[1] = malloc( sizeof( node[511][1] ) ); That is as a pointer to the first element of a two dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

> So are `test` and `test1` basically the same except `test` is on the stack and `test1` on the heap?

Yes, freely speaking, we can say that. With a disclaimer, these are different types.

> `test2` looks like a pointer to an array. does `malloc` allocate `511 * sizeof(node)` to each pointer or to the entire array?

Again, freely speaking we can say to each pointer, wich in this case also happens to be the entire array, as you only allocate 1 block of 511 nodes.

This is a pointer to array of 511, as such you should only assing to it blocks of memory that are multiples of `511 * sizeof(node)`. You could assign to it something like:

```
node (*test2)[511] = malloc(sizeof(node) * 511 * 5);
```

In which case you would have an array of 5 `node (*test2)[511]`. You can equate this to `node test2[5][511]` as the access notation is the same.

> If the later then can we access each node with `test2[i]` and if the former can do the following:
>
> ```
> node  (*test2)[511] = malloc(sizeof(node));
> ```
>
> and then access each node with `test2[i]`?

This allocation is not correct. `test2[0]` points to the first block of 511 nodes, specifically to the first element of each block of 511 nodes, `test2[1]` points to the first element of the next block of 511 nodes, you can't use this pointer to access individual nodes, with the exception of each first node of every block of 511 nodes.

The access to individual nodes must be made with, for instance `test2[0][1]`, for the second node (index 1) of the first block of 511 nodes.

So, again, the allocation must be of blocks of multiples of `511 * sizeof(node)`.

> In general whats the difference between `*test1` and `(*test2)`?

That's it, `test1` is a pointer to `node`, `test2` is a pointer to array of 511 nodes. The previous explanations should make the difference noted.

`test1` is used to access any member of each block of the node array, `test2` is used to access each block of 511 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

> *is the following correct:*
>
> 1. *`test` is an array of 511 nodes. we can access each node with `test[i]` where `i` is the node we want*

Yes

> 2. *`test1` is a pointer where we `malloc` space for 511 nodes. we can access each node with `test1[i]`*

Yes.

> *so are `test` and `test1` basically the same except test is on the stack and test1 on the heap?*

There is no concept of stack or heap in C standard, however, keeping that aside, they are not the same. `test` is an array and `test1` is a pointer, they are different types altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and added also a 4th alternative. And I will post a program and discussion that can be useful on making this a bit more clear.

I believe that this line

```
    Node*   test1 = malloc(_SIZE_ * sizeof(Node));
```

is key to understand how things can get confused. `malloc()` returns just a pointer to an area of the size of the argument. In fact these 2 lines are similar

```
   int* example =  malloc(511);
   Node*   test1 = malloc(_SIZE_ * sizeof(Node));
```

and it illustrates why people from C++ make it mandatory to cast a type for the return of `malloc()` like in

```
   int*  example =  (int*) malloc(511);
   Node*   test1 = (Node*) malloc(_SIZE_ * sizeof(Node));
```

it makes things clearer, they said. And I believe. This way we see that `test1` is just a pointer to `Node` and it can warn us that maybe things are going wrong, or may be not as we expected: it makes no difference the number of bytes allocated, it will be a `NODE*`. A pointer to an area.

### back to the test[123] stuff here

#### test1 as

```
    Node*   test1 = malloc(_SIZE_ * sizeof(Node));
```

`test1` is just a pointer to `Node`. `malloc()` will happily assign how many bytes as it evaluates from the argument. Even less than the size of one `Node`, and the program may crash real fast... or 511 bytes, making no practical difference in the test but bringing it to this topic in SO :)

#### test

```
    #define _SIZE_ 16
    Node    test[_SIZE_];
```

test is just an array of Node

```
typedef struct node
{
    int number;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
}   Node;
```

#### test2

```
Node    (*test2)[_SIZE_] = malloc(_SIZE_ * sizeof(Node));
```

This is not frequently seen because it is not flexible: `test2` is a pointer to an array of `[_SIZE_]` elements of `Node`. A thing just like `test`. In fact I will show below that is perfectly ok to write

```
Node    test[_SIZE_];
Node    (*test2)[_SIZE_] = &test;
```

because this is just the definition of the thing `test2` points to.But as the `_SIZE_` must the known at compile time it is rarely used. Instead we have things much more flexible like the familiar

```
int main(int argc, char** argv);
```

#### And introducing test3

```
Node** test3;
```

Here `test3` is a pointer to an array of pointers to `Node`, and this is the useful way, as every C or C++ or any program knows about.
Let us fill it in

```
    Node** test3 = (Node**)malloc(sizeof(Node*) * _SIZE_);
    for (int i = 0; i < _SIZE_; i += 1)
    {
        test3[i] = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        test3[i]->number = 1000 + i;
    };
```

Now `test3` points to an area of `_SIZE_` times the `sizeof()` of a pointer to `NODE`. And we go into the area and set up the individual pointers to a real `NODE`, each and every one. And we put a value into the number member of each Node so we can print it later in the example program.

- What is the difference? Now we can iterate over the Nodes just like we do over and over again on `argv[i]`
- What is missing? The size information. This is why we have `argc` in every program. We could write

```
// now to iterate over Nodes: should be as familiar as
typedef struct 
{
    int     nodec;
    Node**  nodev;

}   NodeArray;
```

so familiar...
And we can pass over `NodeArrays`, iterable arrays of structures, just like the command line arguments...

#### output of the example

```
sizeof(test) = 384
sizeof(test1) = 8
sizeof(test2) = 8

test is Node[_SIZE_]. Values are
     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15

test2 is a pointer to Node[_SIZE_]. So we can assign &test to it

Done. Now the values of test2:
     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15

test2 restored. Now set up from 500
   500   501   502   503   504   505   506   507   508   509   510   511   512   513   514   515

test1 is just a pointer to Node. Let's set it to 300
*test1 is 300

test3 is an array of pointers to Node, set up from 1000:
  1000  1001  1002  1003  1004  1005  1006  1007  1008  1009  1010  1011  1012  1013  1014  1015
```

#### Sample code

```
#define _SIZE_ 16
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int number;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
}   Node;

int main(void)
{
    Node    test[_SIZE_];
    Node*   test1 = malloc(_SIZE_ * sizeof(Node));
    int*    example = malloc(511); // no meaning
    Node    (*test2)[_SIZE_] = malloc(_SIZE_ * sizeof(Node));
    // test2 points to Node[_SIZE_]
    for (int i = 0; i < _SIZE_; i += 1) test[i].number = i;

    printf("sizeof(test) = %zd\n", sizeof(test));
    printf("sizeof(test1) = %zd\n", sizeof(test1));
    printf("sizeof(test2) = %zd\n", sizeof(test2));

    // test is an array of Node
    printf("\ntest is Node[_SIZE_]. Values are \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < _SIZE_; i += 1)
        printf("%6d", test[i].number);
    printf("\n");

    // test2 points to an array of Node
    printf("\ntest2 is a pointer to Node[_SIZE_]. So we can assign &test to it\n");
    void* save = test2; // or it will leak
    test2 = &test;
    printf("\nDone. Now the values of test2:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < _SIZE_; i += 1)
        printf("%6d", (*test2)[i].number);
    printf("\n");

    test2 = save; // restored
    printf("\ntest2 restored. Now set up from 500\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < _SIZE_; i += 1) (*test2)[i].number = 500 + i;
    for (int i = 0; i < _SIZE_; i += 1)
        printf("%6d", (*test2)[i].number);
    printf("\n");

    // test1 is just a pointer to node
    printf("\ntest1 is just a pointer to Node. Let's set it to 300\n");
    test1->number = 300;
    printf("*test1 is %d\n", test1->number);

    // now to iterate over Nodes: should be as familiar as
    typedef struct 
    {
        int     nodec;
        Node**  nodev;

    }   NodeArray;

    //Node** test3;
    Node** test3 = (Node**)malloc(sizeof(Node*) * _SIZE_);
    for (int i = 0; i < _SIZE_; i += 1)
    {
        test3[i] = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        test3[i]->number = 1000 + i;
    };
    // test3 is an array of Node
    printf("\ntest3 is an array of pointers to Node, set up from 1000:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < _SIZE_; i += 1)
        printf("%6d", test3[i]->number);
    printf("\n");

    // now free() all this
    // test is static
    free(test1); // test1 is Node*
    // test2 is Node (*)[]
    free(test2);
    // test3 is a pointer to an array of pointers...
    for (int i = 0; i < _SIZE_; i += 1) free(test3[i]);
    // all gone
    test3 = NULL; // invalidate it
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score -3):

i think 1,2 are correct test2 it's an array of pointers and accessing node would be like *test[i] and think the declaration is just like that `node  (*test2)[511];` without `malloc(511 * sizeof(node))`
Edit:
then filling the array like this

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 511)
{
 test2[i] = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
 i++;
}
```