# casting a pointer to a float or pointing to a function with a pointer parameter

Tags: c, pointers, parameters

I am trying to understand exactly what this line of code is, as I am learning C.

```
int (*f) (float *)
```

I know the first part is a pointer to an int named f, however the second part is what I am unsure of.

Would this be classed as a pointer to an int named f which is cast to a pointer-to-float

or

Would this be a pointer named f, pointing to a function with a pointer parameter.

Would be great if someone could help and possible explain why or the difference between the two as I am having a little trouble understanding this concept.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tool to explain C code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667362/tool-to-explain-c-code)

Answer (score 3):

That line declares `f` as a pointer to a function accepting a `float *` as its argument and returning an `int`.

The declaration may seem tricky, but it is just following the rules of C. If we wrote

```
int *f(float *);
```

Then it would seem as though `f` is a function returning `int *`. Thus, the correct precedence must be forced using parenthesis around `*f`.

Comment: great, so does this mean that the pointer `f` will only accept a `float *` and nothing else?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how `f` is defined, assigned a function pointer, and then called

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(float *real)
{
    float num = *real + 0.5F;
    return (int)num;
}

int main(void)
{
    float number = 4.9F;
    int (*f) (float *) = foo;           // define f
    printf("%d\n", f(&number));         // calls f
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
5
```

Comment: I went with the question, but it would have been clearer without a pointer argument `*real` (which I didn't put to good use) giving one more `*` than is really necessary to illustrate the use of a function pointer.

Answer (score 1):

It declares `f` as a pointer to a function taking a `float *` (*a `float` pointer*) and returning `int`. You can then use it like this

```
float array[5] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
printf("%d\n", f(array));
```

Comment: `3.5` is not a `float *`.

Answer (score 1):

If you had the declaration:

```
int foo(float *);
```

it would be clear that it was a function definition.  Using `(*f)` instead of `foo` gives you a pointer to a function.